# Can I migrate a roster from an ejabberd server to Google Apps

Tags: g-suite, xmpp, ejabberd

I currently run a jabber server, using eJabberd, and I'd like to move to using a Google Apps instead of running my server.

Is there a way to transfer a user's roster/contact list from eJabberd to a Google Chat account? This would avoid users being required to add their contacts again, which in some cases will require authorization from the other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my tool [jabber-migrate](https://github.com/jirutka/jabber-migrate):

> This tool simplifies migrating of a roster (contact list in XMPP terminology) from one Jabber server (including GTalk!) to another.

Note: I'm the author of this tool.

Comment: Upvoted.........